# How to mock/spy class java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

Tags: java, mockito, java-19

I am getting below error when I am using Java 19. I tried using `--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED`, but that also does not help to resolve below issue. How can I mock ThreadLocalRandom when using Java 19? I am not getting any error if I use Java 17 or below version. Below is the code that generates this error.

```java
final ThreadLocalRandom random = Mockito.mock(ThreadLocalRandom.class);
Mockito.when(random.nextInt(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(0);
```

> [ERROR] Failures:
> [ERROR] Mockito
> Cannot mock/spy class java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
> Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
>
> final classes
> anonymous classes
> primitive types

I tried `--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED`. I am expecting it should work as it was working in Java 17.

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom is a final class in jdk19+, I can imagine the class not being final in lower versions. It's not possible to bypass this without changing the java standard library, as far as I know.

Comment: Why are you wanting to mock a library class in the first place?

Comment: Library class is already mocked a long time back by some one in some unit tests, i am upgrading the jdk version.

Comment: I am afraind there is no simple fix. If you want to still upgrade the Java version you will need to share here the code of you service in which this "random" is being used. We might propose a workaround solution, which will involve change of implementation of the service and the tests code.

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom` extends the base class `Random`. It should be possible to mock `Random` (and your code shouldn't care whether it gets a `Random` or a `ThreadLocalRandom` – LSP)

Comment: I did tried to use Random but then i encountered below error.java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.util.Random(java.lang.Void) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2957fcb0
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)